# How to add a missing value to a time series in order to calculate autocorrelations

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, missing-data

This is my first time posting here, so I hope I am doing this correctly.

I have intensive longitudinal data and want to calculate the autocorrelation function.

The data was collected daily for 5 days for 15 weeks. I want to calculate the autocorrelation across the whole period, but I do not want to have a lag between the last day of week 1 and the first day of week 2 (because they are 3 months apart).

So, I would like to insert a missing value between these two observations.

The data would look like this:

| ID | Week | Emotion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

And I want it to look like this

| ID | Week | Emotion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Are you using R by chance? If so, use this:

````
## simulate data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x1 <- rnorm(n) ; x2 <- rnorm(n) ; x3 <- rnorm(n)
y <- 1 + 2*x1 -1*x2 + 1*x3 + rnorm(n)

## organize into matrix
raw <- cbind(y, x1, x2, x3)

## simulate missingness
naMat <- matrix(rbinom(n*4, 1, .7),
                nrow=nrow(raw), ncol=ncol(raw))
naMat[naMat==0] <- NA

## remove observations
data <- raw * naMat
```
````

Comment: Yes, I am. I am wondering how can I do it for each of the weeks (I have 15 in total). I found this now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350950/inserting-a-new-row-to-data-frame-for-each-group-id. But this is only for the end of each ID, but I need it for each week

Comment: The code above will simulate missing at random, which is probably what you want. Missing not at random is a different story.

For your situation, why not just split the data set into N data frames that you have and run ACF/PACF on each?